# how to make variable from eloquent select

Tags: laravel, variables, eloquent, laravel-authentication

i have this code for select id from table petugas and have statement where from auth

```
$petugas = petugas::where('ID_PETUGAS','=',auth()->user()->id);
```

and i want put that id to this code

```
Peminjaman::create([
            'ID_ANGGOTA' => $request->ID_ANGGOTA,
            'ID_BUKU' => $request->ID_BUKU,
            'ID_PETUGAS' => $petugas->ID_PETUGAS, --> to this
            'TANGGAL_PINJAM' => $request->TANGGAL_PINJAM,
            'TANGGAL_KEMBALI' => $request->TANGGAL_KEMBALI
        ]);
```

how to take the input of these variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first() method:

```
$petugas = petugas::where('ID_PETUGAS','=',auth()->user()->id)->first();
```

Then

```
echo $petugas->ID_PETUGAS;
```

Comment: i got this message, "Trying to get property 'ID_PETUGAS' of non-object"

Comment: The field id_petugas does exist in the table? You must replace "id_petugas" by the field you need.

Comment: sorry i doing a mistake from read the right column